# jQuery in Meteor having trouble finding DOM selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, meteor

Here is the template whose DOM elements I am trying to control:

```
 <template name='libraryTemplate'>
    <div class="container-fluid library_container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1 id='maglens_library_header'>MY LIBRARY</h1>
                <div id='library_page_break'></div>
                <div id='folders_text'>
                    Folders:
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <a class='button-text btn' id='add_new_button'>ADD NEW</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 folders" id='google_drive_thumbnail'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And here is the jQuery Im using to do so.  My `$('body')` selector works fine, and my log statement just inside `$(document).ready()` behaves correctly, but why can't I target the selector `$('.folders')`?  Upon inspection of the DOM, I can see exactly where the code is, but it's like jQuery thinks it doesnt exist?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('document ready');
    $('.folders').on('click', function(){
        console.log('folders clicked');
    })
    // $('body').on('click', function(){
    //  console.log('body clicked');
    // })
});
```

Comment: why don't  simply use template events?

Comment: since `.folders` do not have any text inside of the div, are you sure you are clicking on the correct div? Try `console.log($('folders').length()` in `$(document).ready()` and see what it outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any selectors named `folders`.

I do see `<div id='folders_text'>`.

That's why your body event fires but your other one doesn't.

Secondly, you should be using template events, you're working with Meteor now.

```
Template.libraryTemplate.events({
  'click .folders': function() { console.log('clicked') }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely recommend using the meteor events as everyone else suggested.

What you had actually works, it is just since the div with the "folders" class has no content, the div is very small (unless you have a height attribute on ".folders" or "#google_drive_thumbnail") and thus very hard to click on. Inspect element on the div and you'll see the size